# How to qualify variable inside trigger body (PL/SQL )?

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I can explicitly qualify variable in the body of stored procedure or function :

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE ptest  AS
int_val INT;
BEGIN
  ptest.int_val:=0;
END;
/
```

How to do the same inside trigger ?

```
 create table temp1(id int not null);

 create or replace trigger trg_before_insert_temp1 before insert  on temp1 for each row
declare int_val int;
 begin

   trg_before_insert_temp1.int_val := 0; -- PLS-00201, identifier must be declared

 end trg_before_insert_temp1;
 /
```

Comment: Why do you need it? `int_val := 0;` should be all you need in the trigger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's just an example :) I may want,for instance , to insert/update another table, `insert into ... returning some_field into int_val`. And in general, I believe specifying everything explicitly makes the code more readable and less error-prone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting question.  As far as I can tell, this is not possible, though it seems like it should be.  Unless someone else can show how it can be done, a workaround would be to nest the code in a block:

```
create or replace trigger trg_before_insert_temp1 before insert on temp1 for each row
declare
begin
   <<bob>> declare
      int_val int;
   BEGIN
      bob.int_val := 0; 
   END;
end trg_before_insert_temp1;
```

Comment: Why is there an empty `declare` before `begin`? And why `declare` is inside `begin`?